# Maximum length of a sequence

Tags: number-theory

I have to find out the maximum length of an increasing sequence of 3 digit numbers such that the numbers reversed(as in 123 becomes 321) form a decreasing sequence.

I don't really know where to start on this one. Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following constraints:

- For the forward numbers increasing:

  - The first digit must increase OR
  - The first digit stays constant and the second digit increases
- For the reverse numbers decreasing:

  - The third digit decreases
  - The third digit stays constant and second digit decreases

We note that both the first digit and the third digit cannot stay constant, as it forces the second digit to have contradictory constraints.

Therefore, either the first or the last digit must increase in each term of the sequence.

An example sequence is: $$159, 249, 258, 348, 357, 447, 456, 546, 555, 645, 654, 744, 753, 843, 852, 942, 951$$

This is the maximum length you can achieve, which is $9 \times 2 - 1 = 17$.

Comment: Looks correct. Thanks!

Comment: I think we could also add for example 960 to the sequence, since the question does specify that the reverse sequence must contain 3 digit numbers. That would make for a length of 18, but I'm not sure it's allowed.

Comment: I meant to say it doesnt specify*

Comment: Right, I think we can do that and extend to 18.